# Maya Python mirroring issue

Tags: python, maya, maya-api

I want to mirror an object in maya "object1" and delete it's original version after the mirroring

```
cmds.polyMirrorFace("object1",name="object1Mirror",cutMesh=0,axis=0,axisDirection=1, mergeMode=0, mergeThresholdType=0, mergeThreshold=0.001, mirrorAxis=2, mirrorPosition=0, smoothingAngle=30, flipUVs=1, ch=0);
cmds.delete("object1")
```

But the polyMirrorFace gives me one merged object besides the fact that I thought I've deactivated merging with mergeMode=0.

When I mirror in maya via UI, it works fine.

I hope, somebody can help.

Comment: When you mirror in maya via the UI, check the script editor and see what command Maya used to successfully perform the mirroring. I tried the same command you used and (probably due to my different maya version) I got several errors for some of those flags you used were not available for me, and some I couldn't find in the documentation, like `smoothingAngle`, `flipUVs`..

Comment: When you mirror in maya via the UI, check the script editor and see what command Maya used to successfully perform the mirroring. I tried the same command you used and (probably due to my different maya version) I got several errors for some of those flags you used were not available for me, and some I couldn't find in the documentation, like `smoothingAngle`, `flipUVs` https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2016/CHS/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/polyMirrorFace.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this logic:

```
# mirror about +Y direction by merging the border vertices
import maya.cmds as mc

mc.polyCube( name='polyCube5' )

# deliberately deleting face `1`
mc.delete( 'polyCube5.f[1]' )

# mirror about +Y direction
mc.polyMirrorFace( 'polyCube5', direction=0, mergeMode=2 )

# deleting all faces but a target
mc.delete( 'polyCube5.f[0:9]' )
```

or this logic to delete source object and leave a duplicate:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

cmds.polyCube( name='poly1' )
cmds.move( -1, y=True )
cmds.duplicate( st=True )
cmds.move( 2, y=True )
cmds.delete( 'poly1' )
```

ADDITION:

```
import maya.cmds as mc

mc.polyHelix(c=3, h=2, w=2, r=0.4, sa=8, sco=50, sc=0, d=1, rcp=0, cuv=3, ch=1) 
mc.scale(1,1,-1, 'pHelix1', pivot=(0,0,0), absolute=True)
```

Comment: That works for most of the cases, I guess. It gets funnier when you do that with imported objects. Lets say, you import an object from a .mb including several groups, mirror it one by one and than export as obj e.g. But yes, your version works. Thanks for that!

Comment: Thanks, stil I have the issue if I iterate through multiple objects that they are merged. Somehow this seems to be bugged.

Comment: cmds.polyHelix(c=3, h=2, w=2 ,r=0.4 ,sa=8 , sco=50 ,sc=0, d=1 , rcp=0 ,cuv=3 ,ch= 1)

sel = cmds.ls(geometry=True)

for obj in sel:
   cmds.polyMirrorFace(obj,  mm=0, cm=True)

Comment: It does not format my code correctly, I hope it is understandable. It creates a helix, mirrors it (and any other object) but I always get a merged helix regardless of the options I use for mirroring.

Comment: In this case you can use 'scale' = -1 along Z axis. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you, but there is a difference between scaling by -1 and the mirroring as UVs and normals are not mirrored. But I get your point basically, thank you.